# Set Keystone List "noedit" based on field value?

Tags: keystonejs

I would like to make my Keystone List object editable only if the object is not published. Here's my reduced List definition:

```
var Campaign = new keystone.List('Campaign', {
  nodelete: true,
  track: {
    createdAt: true,
  },
});

Campaign.add({
  ...,
  publish: {
    type: Types.Boolean,
    required: false,
    initial: false,
    dependsOn: {
      publishedOn: '',
    },
  },
  publishedOn: {
    type: Types.Datetime,
    label: 'Published On',
    hidden: true,
  },
});
```

Is it possible to set `noedit` only if `publishedOn` is not null? I'm trying to prevent the object from being modified after it's "published", and am coming up short on examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interestingly, I was able to make the `publish` field simply check itself:

```
Campaign.add({
  ...,
  publish: {
    type: Types.Boolean,
    required: false,
    initial: false,

    dependsOn: {
      publish: false,
    },

  },
  ...,
});
```

and now it only shows if `publish` is `false`, which works exactly as I hoped it would.

Answer (score 0):

The `noedit` property for a list or field is part of the model definition, and not part of the definition of an individual item. There is no way to mark a single item as uneditable in the admin UI unless you want to apply it to the field or model as a whole.

If you are less worried about clarity, and more worried about ensuring it cannot be edited, you could try the following:

```
Campaign.schema.post('init', function () {
    if (this.published) this.invalidate('Published items cannot be edited');
});
```

This will cause an error to be thrown if you attempt to save the item once it is published.

While you could use `dependsOn: { published: { $exists: true } }` to filter fields, this would hide the information.